# How can I connect ORACLE from EXCEL with JDBC?

Tags: oracle, excel, jdbc

I want to connect oracle with JDBC from excel.
I want to insert data to oracle when I click the button in excel, I dont want to install ora-client.Is it possible with jdbc?
I use Microsoft.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using JDBC to connect to Oracle from Excel doesn't make much sense (JDBC is a Java framework for connecting to databases and therefore not suitable for Excel IMHO).

You should install the Oracle Data Access components for Windows (assuming you're using Windows; good luck if you're using a Mac); then, you can

- directly use Oracle as a data source (no need for macros); there are tons of tutorials available on the web for this, see e.g. [MacLochlainns Weblog: Query Oracle Database](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/how-to-query-oracle-from-excel-2007/)
- write Excel plugins in .NET, using the standard .NET mechanisms to connect to Oracle databases (again, lots of tutorials available on the Web)

Comment: thanks for reply, I want to insert data to oracle when I click the button in excel, I dont want to install ora-client.Is it possible with jdbc?

Comment: jdbc can be used only in a java (family) language. That thing you described looks like a macro to me and as far as i know you are not allow to use java. Anyways, you could need a driver in your journey ant this could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495909/alternative-oracle-drivers-for-net

Comment: @fGo Can I connect oracle with ddl which I convert to jdbc.jar to that ddl.

Comment: @ersin sorry but i didn't understand your question. If by DDL you mean _Data Definition Language_ it really doesn't make any sense, otherwise please detail what do you want to know as much as possible

Comment: Why do you insist on using JDBC? Did you even try what I suggested to you?