# Convert Number 1,000 from excel to plsql become 1000

Tags: excel, oracle, csv, plsql, formbuilder

I will make a program for upload file excel to oracle with utl file,and my data will be like.

```
Quantity 
1,000 
5,000 
4,000
```

can i convert **1,000** become **1000** in plsql?

can i import file excel to oracle without converting that file to csv format?

Thankyou.

Comment: What is wrong with exporting your spreadsheet as CSV and then loading it into Oracle?

Comment: loading it with? sql developer ? sorry i am newbie in oracle

Answer (score 1):

Excel is generally too complicated a format for importing (old "xls" versus new "xlsx", formulas, multiple worksheets, date formats, hidden columns...)

Delimited files (such as CSV), fixed length files, XML or JSON are better for exchanging information between systems.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to load an Excel spreadsheet directly into Oracle is by using ODBC. You would need to install an Oracle client and the ODBC driver for Oracle database. There are many detailed how-tos available, this is one example:
[Connecting Excel VBA to oracle DB using 'ODBC'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339682/connecting-excel-vba-to-oracle-db-using-odbc)