# Connecting Excel VBA to oracle DB using 'ODBC' (continue of 37339682)

Tags: oracle, excel, ms-access, vba

This question is a continuation of question 37339682: [Connecting Excel VBA to oracle DB using 'ODBC'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339682/)

In the above question, there is a step by step guide to connect Excel to ODBC. (Oracle database) I have successful connected to the Oracle database and retrieve a table.

My questions are: 
(1) How to write Excel VBA code, such that it can read SQL query from a cell, and return the SQL query result in a table. I guess I need to setup a "database object" in the Excel VBA code.

(2) If such code are to be performed in Microsoft Access. How different would it be?

Comment: Have a look at this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OLEDB/using.htm#OLEDB219 It uses OLE DB, however the code with ODBC should be very similar, I assume just the ConnectionString would be different.

Answer (score 0):

Not a database object but a recordset object

```
 Sub Example
 Dim rs as New Recordset  'the new is important
 Dim Conn as New Connection
 Conn.connectionstring = "whatever"
```

'see here https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-for-oracle/

```
 Conn.open
 Dim sql as string
 sql = "whatever"  'could be text in cell ie sql = range("g1").text
 rs.open sql,conn
 if not rs.eof then  'if there's any data then
     Activesheet.range("a2").copyfromrecordset rs  'puts data into cell
 End If
 rs.close
 conn.close
 end sub
```