# Simplest way to connect to Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am making a desktop application in C#. What's the simplest way to connect to Oracle? The application is a very simple one and it will only run a few SELECT and INSERT statements.

Don't want to install some big drivers or clients on my machine. Anything that will make my application up and running quickly is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative Oracle drivers for .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495909/alternative-oracle-drivers-for-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use the

[Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

which is apparently included in WDAC (Windows Data Access Components) and, thus, in certain versions of Windows. I couldn't find a comprehensive list, though, you might have to verify that it works on the target OSes of your application yourself.

Do note, though, that this simplicity comes at a price -- the driver is deprecated:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Windows. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use Oracle’s OLE DB provider.

Comment: I guess meaning it is deprecated makes is a bad thing to use in a new product. There is an easier solution though, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Oracle Managed .NET driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html). It doesn't require OCI to be installed which makes it very easy to deploy. Another nice thing of it, is that is supports both 32 and 64 bit (the unmanaged  version of the ODP.NET driver didn't).

Comment: This one also looks good. Will keep that in mind for future programs.

Comment: @FrankMartin: I would suggest to do it now. It is much easier to use that any of the other methods provided, and it will stay longer than the OLE DB Oracle stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use standalone approach as described [here](http://ialekseev.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/using-oracle-in-standalone-net.html).

In short, you just need few necessary files from the Oracle Client to reside in the *bin* folder of your application, to work with Oracle database. There is no need to install heavy Oracle client or use other providers that may not exist on some machines.